# How to re-render a component with React-Router <Link> pointing to the same URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs

To keep it simple, the detail page fetches data on mount based on the movie ID in the URL, this coming from path='movie/:id' in the Route.

It's child is called Recommended, which shows you recommended movies based again on the current URL.

```
class MovieDetailPage extends React.Component {

    // Fetch movies and cast based on the ID in the url
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getMovieDetails(this.props.match.params.id)
        this.props.getMovieCast(this.props.match.params.id)
    }



    render() {            
        <div>
          Movies here
        </div>
        <Recommended id={this.props.match.params.id}/>
    }
}
```

The Recommended component fetches data based on the current movie as well and generates another  tag pointing to another movie.

```
class Recommended extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getRecommended(this.props.id)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
            <Category title={'Recommended'}></Category>
            <div className="movies">
                {   
                    this.props.recommended.map((movie) => {
                        return (
                            <Link key={movie.id} to={`movie/${movie.id}`} className="movies__item">
                                <img
                                    key={movie.id}
                                    src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342${movie.poster_path}`} 
                                    className="movies__item-img"
                                    alt={`A poster of ${movie.title}`}
                                >
                                </img>
                            </Link>
                        )                      
                    })
                }
            </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

Now how can I trigger another render of the parent component when clicking the Link generated in the Recommended component? The URL is changing but this won't trigger a render like I intent to do.

**UPDATE:**

```
<Route 
  path="/movie/:id" 
  render={(props) => (
  <MovieDetailPage key={props.match.params.id} 
  {...props} 
  )}
/>
```

I passed in a unique key this time that triggered the re-render of the page. I tried this before but I might've screwed up the syntax.

This post got me in the right direction: [Force remount component when click on the same react router Link multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57786965/force-remount-component-when-click-on-the-same-react-router-link-multiple-times)

Answer (score 5):

## Add a key to the page

If you change route but your page is not getting its "mount" data then you should add a key to the page. This will cause your page to rerender and mount with the new id and get the data again.

You can read more about react keys [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)

A key tells react that this is a particular component, this is why you see them in on lists. By changing the key on your page you tell react that this is a new instantiation of the component and has changed. This will cause a remount.

## Class component example

```
class MyPage extends React.Component {
    componentDidMound() {
      // this will fire each time the key changes since it triggers a mount
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div key={props.pageId}>
               {/* component stuff */} 
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

## Functional component example

```
const MyPage = (props) => {
    React.useEffect(() => {
      // this will fire each time the key changes
    }, []);

    return (
        <div key={props.pageId}>
           {/* component stuff */} 
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Could you perhaps extend on this? I'm not sure on how to add a key to the MovieDetail component. Do I pass this key in via the Route like so:



<Route path="/movie/:id" component={MovieDetailPage} key={someKey}/>



Or elsewhere? I can rerender the Recommended component by passing it a key but my intention is to cause the Parent to render again when clicking a Link generated in the child.

Comment: The page component should have some detail inside its props. One of those things will be a url or at least the :id. Use that too add the key to the top level component.

Comment: Forgive if I'm being ignorant, I'm still quite new to React but I thought you couldn't pass props from Child to a Parent component? I guess the top component in my App is the a class component which has the BrowserRouter with all of the Routes inside. I do have access to the new path but I have no clue how to pass that prop 'up' and create a key based on that prop. The only way it 'works' at the moment is me manually refreshing the page since my URL does change on clicking a movie and thus on refresh and getting mounted, paints accordingly.

Comment: Nevermind! Went back at it again and tried to do basically the same and this time it worked like a charm! I updated my post. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hey Good job!! thats exactly what i meant. Sorry if i didn't explain it as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can add another React lifecycle method that triggers on receiving new props (UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps, componentDidUpdate, getDerivedStateFromProps) in your Recommended component like this:

```
UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.id !== this.props.id) {
    nextProps.getRecommended(nextProps.id);
  };
}
```

You can also add key to your component (which forces it to re-render completely if key changed) like this:

`<Recommended key={this.props.match.params.id} id={this.props.match.params.id}/>`

You can also use React Hooks to handle this more easily with useEffect:

```
const Recommended = (props) => {
  const { id, getRecommended, recommended } = props;
  useEffect(() => {
    id && getRecommended(id);
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <>
      <Category title={'Recommended'}></Category>
      <div className="movies">
        {recommended.map((movie) => {
          return (
            <Link key={movie.id} to={`movie/${movie.id}`} className="movies__item">
              <img
                key={movie.id}
                src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342${movie.poster_path}`}
                className="movies__item-img"
                alt={`A poster of ${movie.title}`}
              ></img>
            </Link>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

**Note**: adding key to component and complete its re-render is not best practice and you should be using Component's lifecycles to avoid it if possible