# React-router. History.replace without change location.key

Tags: reactjs, url, parameters, react-router

I have two tasks:

1. Reload the filter component when I am on the same path, via the sidebar and navbar menus using Link and history.push or history.replace.
2. When loading the page, update url params from the server. Here's the problem.

Solutions:

1. Assign a key to a component.

```
<Filter key = {location.key} .../>
```

Everything works well, the component is rerender every time.

2. When I update url params using history.push, location.key changes. An endless rerender cycle occurs.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to avoid changing location.key when updating params?
2. Is it possible to update params without history.replace?

Thanks.
Update:
This is my page code. getFiltersInfo gives me information for filters. In Filter component, I build it in the form of inputs and selects. In Filter component, I add params to url via history.replace. The location.key changes and the filter component is rerender. It does history.replace again. This is an endless loop.

```
 ...
  const [exportData, SetExportData]=useState({})
 
useEffect(() => {
  DataService.getFiltersInfo()
  .then((response) => {
    setItems3(response)
    setSuccess(true)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    setSuccess(false)
  });
}, [ ]);

useUpdateEffect(() => {
  let send = {
    page: carentPage,
    per_page: perPage,
    filters: exportData
  }

   DataService.postUsers2(send)
   .then((response) => {
       if(response.items) {
         setItems1(response.items);
         setItems2(response._meta);
     }else{
       setSuccess(false)
     }
   })
   .catch((error) => {
     setSuccess(false)
   });

}, [exportData]);
 
 
  const renderFilter = (): any => {
 
    if (Object.keys(items3).length){
  
      return <Filter key={location.key} items={filterItems} inputData={items3} updateExportData={SetExportData} show={showFilter}/>
    }else{
   
      return null
     }
  }
 
 ...
 
  return (
    <div className="content">
    ...
 
      <Link to="/caf/utilisateurs">sss</Link>
          {success==true && <>
          {renderFilter()}
          <BootstrapTable
            bordered={false}
            keyField="id"
            data={items1}
            columns={columns}
            rowStyle={TableFormatter.meduimTable}
          />
 ...
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is the Filter component code. Export function is triggered once during rendering and subsequent times on the button. history.replace causes an endless loop.

```
  ...
  const Export = ()=>{
 
  let result = Object.assign({}, output);
  let query=""
    Object.keys(result).forEach(function(key) {
      if(result[key] === 0) {
        result[key] = null;
      }
      if(result[key] === "" ||result[key] === "0") {
        result[key] = null;
      }
     
       if (key.indexOf('date') > -1) {
           if(result[key] !== null){
            result[key] = moment(result[key]).format("YYYY-MM-DD")  
           }
      }
  })
 
   history.replace({
   pathname: path,
   search:DataModifier.objectToParams(result)
  })
  updateExportData(result)
  
  }
 ...
```

Here is a link to my infinite loop situation: https://codesandbox.io/s/history-replace-test-forked-wiqvk

Comment: why are you using `location.key` ? I still don't understand why you have an endless loop ? Maybe you can show us a little bit more of your code

Comment: Likely, they are trying to re-render the component given the route doesn't change so they use `key` to force a re-render.

Comment: @Alex, i think it's the opposite, they want to use the key to make sure it's not doing the render for the same path.

Comment: Sure, without additional code it's hard to say. I'm talking about common questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60416677/how-to-re-render-a-component-with-react-router-link-pointing-to-the-same-url)

Comment: A suggestion, please print out all `location.key` with a `console.log`. I wonder if the key is an object or not. If it's an object, then you might be able to do `location.key.ABC`, as long as it's a string, you should get less render. However the problem will still persist.

Comment: @Alex, i know what you mean :)

Comment: I agree with @Olivier, why the key, why not just the `pathname` or something, this way you can make sure `Filter` doesn't go crazy. Of course why endless render, there must be a force render somewhere.

Comment: @Olivier Boissé, I added some code and a description logic.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the code.

```
  history.replace({ search: "param=123" });
```

Lines like that will run in all renders. If you do the following, it'll make sure you run it once.

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
   history.replace({ search: "param=123" });
  }, [])
```

This is to resolve to endless loop. The router statement `useLocation` basically manages the browser state.