# Navigate to a search page after a search in the search bar and reuse the search bar within the search page

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

In my React application, at the layout level and in addition to the main content, I have a sidebar and a header with a profile section and a search bar - all different components.

The header goes with every page - routes - and I want to do searches on any route; after doing the search (sent with enter) I go to the "/search" route to display and filter the results.

This is a snippet of code related to the search bar component - form:

```
const SearchSection = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();

  const handleSearch = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (location.pathname !== "/search") {
      navigate("/search", { state: value });
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Box
        component="form"
        onSubmit={handleSearch}
        sx={{ display: { xs: "none", md: "block" } }}
      >
        <OutlineInputStyle
          id="input-search-header"
          value={value}
          onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Search"
        />
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};

export default SearchSection;
```

After the user submits the search (with enter) I navigate to the search page and display the results:

```
const Search = () => {
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const location = useLocation();

  function showResults() {
    const headers = { Accept: "application/ld+json" };
    const response = fetch(
      `http://localhost:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/entities?type=Sensor&q=refRoom~=.*${location.state}`,
      {
        headers,
      }
    )
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        }
        throw response;
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setResults(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error fetching data: ", error);
        setError(error);
      });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    showResults();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Grid container spacing={gridSpacing}>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
          <Table>
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell>ID</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Type</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              {results.map((result) => (
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell>{result.id}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{result.type}</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              ))}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default Search;
```

routes/MainRoutes.js file:

```
import { lazy } from 'react';

import MainLayout from 'layout/MainLayout';
import Loadable from 'ui-component/Loadable';

const DashboardHome = Loadable(lazy(() => import('views/dashboard/Home')));
const SearchPage = Loadable(lazy(() => import('views/search')));

const MainRoutes = {
    path: '/',
    element: <MainLayout />,
    children: [
        {
            path: '/',
            element: <DashboardHome />
        },
        {
            path: '/search',
            element: <SearchPage />
        }
    ]
};

export default MainRoutes;
```

routes/index.js file:

```
import { useRoutes } from 'react-router-dom';
import MainRoutes from './MainRoutes';
import AuthenticationRoutes from './AuthenticationRoutes';

export default function ThemeRoutes() {
    return useRoutes([MainRoutes, AuthenticationRoutes], config.basename);
}
```

App.js file:

```
import { FirebaseProvider } from 'contexts/Firebase';
import Routes from 'routes';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <FirebaseProvider>
            <>
                <Routes />
            </>
        </FirebaseProvider>
    );
};

export default App;
```

The user can start the search on any route and, regardless of where he is, he is redirected to `/search`. The search bar is a subcomponent of the `MainLayout` component. The `MainLayout` component has the sidebar, header (which has the search bar) and main content, with the latter being the `SearchPage` component, `DashboardHome`, etc.

So far it works fine, the problem appears when I want to re-use the search bar already inside the /search route - it doesn't refresh the page.

How do I solve this problem and/or what is the best approach?

Comment: because you are using `location.state` and it will not rerender the page, you need to manually rerender the page by sending different key

Comment: might be this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60416677/how-to-re-render-a-component-with-react-router-link-pointing-to-the-same-url

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share all the relevant code you are working with, i.e. the routes, the sidebar, the search component, etc... We can't really help diagnose or debug code we can't see. See [mcve].

Comment: It's still missing a lot of context. Where is the search initiated? I assume after initiating a search the user is redirected to `"/search"` and the `SearchPage` component is rendered. It's still not clear what the issue is. Can you provide all the relevant code?

Comment: @DrewReese You are right. The user can start the search on any route and, regardless of where he is, he is redirected to `/search`. The search bar is a subcomponent of the `MainLayout` component. The `MainLayout` component has the sidebar, header (which has the search bar) and main content, with the latter being the `SearchPage` component, `DashboardHome`, etc.

Comment: So is the issue that a user is already on `"/search"` and the `SearchPage` is rendered, and they search again from the searchbar.... and *nothing* (???) happens? Can we see this `SearchPage` component?

Comment: @DrewReese No, if the user is in "/" - DashboardHome - (or other route than "/search") and performs a search, he is redirected to "/search" and the results are displayed - it works correctly. The problem is when you are inside "/search" and use the search bar again. I've already put the complete code for the search bar component.

Comment: I'm asking to see the code for the component that has the issue rerendering, the `SearchPage` component. Part of the problem is that the `SearchSection` component doesn't do anything if the user is already on the `"/search"` path.

Comment: @DrewReese I updated the question with the code from the `SearchPage` component - second code block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issues

1. The `SearchSection` doesn't navigate to `"/search"` with the new search value when the URL path is already on `"/search".
2. The `SearchPage` component doesn't "listen" to changes in the route state (*from the `location` object*) to invoke `showResults` with the new search parameters.

## Solution

Just navigate to `"/search"` with new search state unconditionally. Or perhaps, only issue the navigation request if there is a search value. When the route state value changes, the `useEffect` hook callback will be called and issue the fetch request.

```
const SearchSection = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleSearch = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (value) {
      navigate("/search", { state: value, replace: true });
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Box
        component="form"
        onSubmit={handleSearch}
        sx={{ display: { xs: "none", md: "block" } }}
      >
        <OutlineInputStyle
          id="input-search-header"
          value={value}
          onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Search"
        />
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};
```

Unpack the route state and use as a dependency for the `useEffect` hook in `SearchPage`.

```
const Search = () => {
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const { state } = useLocation(); // <-- unpack route state

  useEffect(() => {
    const headers = { Accept: "application/ld+json" };

     // pass in queryString
    const url = `http://localhost:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/entities?type=Sensor&q=refRoom~=.*${state || ''}`;

    fetch(url, { headers })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        }
        throw response;
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setResults(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error fetching data: ", error);
        setError(error);
      });
  }, [state]); // <-- use as effect dependency

  return (
    ...
  );
};
```